# wxpython: ImportError Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib

Tags: wxpython, python-import

Please don't consider this a duplicate. I have spent time trying to understand the answers to similar questions but could not imbibe much because I am new to both python and linux file sytems

I have OSX El Capitan 10.11.3 and Python 2.7.11. 
This shows up on my pip list:

```
    wxPython (3.0.2.0)
    wxPython-common (3.0.2.0)
```

When I run my code(peppy_gui.py) after importing wx, I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "peppy_gui.py", line 3, in <module>
    import wx
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from wx._core import *
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core.py", line 4, in <module>
import _core_
    ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx-3.0-osx_cocoa/wx/_core_.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libpng/lib/libpng16.16.dylib
    Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/wxmac/lib/libwx_osx_cocoau_xrc-3.0.dylib
    Reason: image not found
```

Note: I installed the package using Homebrew

Any suggestions?